# Keep primeng multiselect open on scroll

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeNG multiselect (p-multiselect) as part of a component library, which we're adding into a report with many other multiselects to create filters. Since upgrading to Angular 12, whenever a user scrolls outside of the report, the filter closes. We'd like the filter to remain open. I've tried `appendTo="body"` (results in no change in behavior) and `[appendTo]="container"` (misplaces the overaly on the page entirely) on a containing div, but the desired behavior is still not achieved. Is this possible with primeNG now, to keep the overlay open on scroll?

Comment: you might want to create a stackblitz.com project with a minimal version of the issue... otherwise it would be hard to provide you with help

Comment: You can see that in [the examples on the primeng documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect), the behavior you're describing isn't observed. Please create a working demo of the issue, post your code or add a detailed explanation of your component hierarchy.

Comment: i had the same issue, this is happening to me, when I have a multi-selector inside a modal CDK. angular 13. I looked into the source code, to understand the flow, https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts
seems there is only one strategy regarding scrolling. so I basically find where to deactivate this. see my response below.

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is happening due to the inner scroll-listener strategy, there is no option to modify it, best you can do is to unsubscribe, so the close event won't activate on scroll.

```
<p-multiSelect #multiSelector> </p-multiSelect>
```

You can get the reference of your multi-select instance using ViewChild

```
import { MultiSelect } from 'primeng/multiselect';
@ViewChild('multiSelector') multiSelector: MultiSelect;
```

Then

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.multiSelector.onPanelShow.subscribe(() => {
      this.multiSelector.unbindScrollListener();
    });
  }
```